# Search Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

Is there a way to use Azure Search against Azure File Shares. I only see blob storage as an option. We have on-prem servers that sync files to Azure File Shares and would like to search inside those files in a web application.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, there's no way unless you manually query and push file content to your Azure Cognitive Search index. In the future, there's a hope you'll be able to trigger an Azure Function using this type of binding, which will make your life easier. You can follow / vote up for this feature in the following link:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/14

Answer (score 1):

Per UserVoice Page for Azure Search: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/14274261-indexer-for-azure-file-shares#{toggle_previous_statuses}, Azure File Indexer is available in private preview (in fact this has been in this stage for almost 2 years now :)).

Search team would like to reach out to them in case you're interested.

Comment: I saw that but was hoping it was just dated information.